# Select Inside a select statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a table in Database A from a table in database B. I have an idea with the query. In the database A, the table needs MerchantID and can get it from database B by using the query (Select MerchantID from Merchant_Location where LocationID= 'particular LocationID').

I need some help with the syntax for a query like this in SQL Server 2005. Thank you in advance!

```
INSERT INTO A.dbo.Merchant_Category (MerchantCategoryID, MerchantID)
SELECT MerchantLocationCategoryID, (MerchantID from Merchant_Location where LocationID =    @Location) as MerchantID FROM B.dbo.Merchant_Location_Category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN across databases in an `INSERT`, just like a `SELECT`. Most systems will allow it in an `UPDATE` as well.

```
INSERT INTO A.dbo.Merchant_Category (
   MerchantCategoryID, MerchantID
)
SELECT LC.MerchantLocationCategoryID, L.MerchantId
FROM B.dbo.Merchant_Location_Category as LC
JOIN A.dbo.Merchant_Location as L ON
    LC.LocationID = L.LocationID
```

Comment: I understand that now. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a SELECT INTO statement. What this does is execute a query and then inserts the results into your designated table.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM db_b.TABLE_IN_DB_B
INTO db_a.TABLE_IN_DB_A;
```

Read more about the SELECT INTO statement [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx)